# The specified type was not recognized error while deserializing XML

Tags: c#, xml, deserialization

I'm trying to deserialize the following XML using C#:

```xml
<page totalPages="1" totalNumberOfElements="12113" pageSize="12113" lastUpdate="2021-07-13T19:01:38.432Z" currentPage="1">
    <query />
    <items>
        <item xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:type="product">
            <availability>4</availability>
            <bestTaxable>71.90</bestTaxable>
            <code>1</code>
            <currency>EUR</currency>
            <id>55510</id>
            <pictures>
                <image>
                    <id>600842</id>
                    <url>1.jpg</url>
                </image>
                <image>
                    <id>600843</id>
                    <url>11.jpg</url>
                </image>
            </pictures>
            <intangible>false</intangible>
            <intra />
            <madein>null</madein>
            <models>
                <model>
                    <additionalBarcodes>11</additionalBarcodes>
                    <availability>2</availability>
                    <backorder>false</backorder>
                    <barcode>4064049162606</barcode>
                    <bestTaxable>71.90</bestTaxable>
                    <code>1111</code>
                    <color>white</color>
                    <id>300061</id>
                    <lastUpdate>2021-07-13T16:16:57.906Z</lastUpdate>
                    <model>42</model>
                    <modelWeight>1.0</modelWeight>
                    <size>42</size>
                    <streetPrice>132.00</streetPrice>
                    <suggestedPrice>126.00</suggestedPrice>
                    <taxable>71.90</taxable>
                </model>
                <model>
                    <additionalBarcodes>111</additionalBarcodes>
                    <availability>2</availability>
                    <backorder>false</backorder>
                    <barcode>4064049162521</barcode>
                    <bestTaxable>71.90</bestTaxable>
                    <code>111</code>
                    <color>white</color>
                    <id>300060</id>
                    <lastUpdate>2021-07-13T16:16:57.905Z</lastUpdate>
                    <model>44</model>
                    <modelWeight>1.0</modelWeight>
                    <size>44</size>
                    <streetPrice>132.00</streetPrice>
                    <suggestedPrice>126.00</suggestedPrice>
                    <taxable>71.90</taxable>
                </model>
            </models>
            <name>Adidas Sneakers Uomo</name>
            <online>true</online>
            <localizations>
                <description />
                <metaDescription />
                <metaKeywords />
                <metaTitle />
                <name />
                <urlKey />
            </localizations>
            <streetPrice>132.00</streetPrice>
            <suggestedPrice>126.00</suggestedPrice>
            <tags>
                <tag>
                    <hidden>false</hidden>
                    <id>1</id>
                    <name>brand</name>
                    <priority>0</priority>
                    <value>
                        <value>Adidas</value>
                    </value>
                </tag>
                <tag>
                    <hidden>false</hidden>
                    <id>4</id>
                    <name>category</name>
                    <priority>0</priority>
                    <value>
                        <value>Shoes</value>
                    </value>
                </tag>
                <tag>
                    <hidden>false</hidden>
                    <id>5</id>
                    <name>subcategory</name>
                    <priority>0</priority>
                    <value>
                        <value>Men-Sneakers</value>
                    </value>
                </tag>
                <tag>
                    <hidden>false</hidden>
                    <id>11</id>
                    <name>season</name>
                    <priority>0</priority>
                    <value>
                        <value>Fall/Winter</value>
                    </value>
                </tag>
                <tag>
                    <hidden>false</hidden>
                    <id>13</id>
                    <name>color</name>
                    <priority>0</priority>
                    <value>
                        <value>white</value>
                    </value>
                </tag>
                <tag>
                    <hidden>false</hidden>
                    <id>26</id>
                    <name>gender</name>
                    <priority>0</priority>
                    <value>
                        <value>Men</value>
                    </value>
                </tag>
                <tag>
                    <hidden>true</hidden>
                    <id>30</id>
                    <name>productname</name>
                    <priority>0</priority>
                    <value>
                        <value>OZELIA</value>
                    </value>
                </tag>
                <tag>
                    <hidden>false</hidden>
                    <id>92</id>
                    <name>fastening</name>
                    <priority>0</priority>
                    <value>
                        <value>laces</value>
                    </value>
                </tag>
                <tag>
                    <hidden>false</hidden>
                    <id>104</id>
                    <name>brandType</name>
                    <priority>0</priority>
                    <value>
                        <value>fashion</value>
                    </value>
                </tag>
                <tag>
                    <hidden>false</hidden>
                    <id>108</id>
                    <name>subcategoryGriffati</name>
                    <priority>0</priority>
                    <value>
                        <value>Men-Sneakers</value>
                    </value>
                </tag>
            </tags>
            <taxable>71.90</taxable>
            <vatClassId>1</vatClassId>
            <weight>1.0</weight>
        </item>
        <item xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:type="product">
            <availability>20</availability>
            <bestTaxable>46.90</bestTaxable>
            <code>2</code>
            <currency>EUR</currency>
            <id>2</id>
            <pictures>
                <image>
                    <id>600835</id>
                    <url>2.jpg</url>
                </image>
                <image>
                    <id>600837</id>
                    <url>22.jpg</url>
                </image>
            </pictures>
            <intangible>false</intangible>
            <intra />
            <madein>null</madein>
            <models>
                <model>
                    <additionalBarcodes>222</additionalBarcodes>
                    <availability>3</availability>
                    <backorder>false</backorder>
                    <barcode>22</barcode>
                    <bestTaxable>46.90</bestTaxable>
                    <code>224721_105</code>
                    <color>black</color>
                    <id>22</id>
                    <lastUpdate>2021-07-13T16:16:57.734Z</lastUpdate>
                    <model>XS</model>
                    <modelWeight>0.5</modelWeight>
                    <size>XS</size>
                    <streetPrice>93.09</streetPrice>
                    <suggestedPrice>82.00</suggestedPrice>
                    <taxable>46.90</taxable>
                </model>
                <model>
                    <additionalBarcodes>22</additionalBarcodes>
                    <availability>4</availability>
                    <backorder>false</backorder>
                    <barcode>2222</barcode>
                    <bestTaxable>46.90</bestTaxable>
                    <code>224721_101</code>
                    <color>black</color>
                    <id>2222</id>
                    <lastUpdate>2021-07-13T16:16:57.731Z</lastUpdate>
                    <model>S</model>
                    <modelWeight>0.5</modelWeight>
                    <size>S</size>
                    <streetPrice>93.09</streetPrice>
                    <suggestedPrice>82.00</suggestedPrice>
                    <taxable>46.90</taxable>
                </model>
                <model>
                    <additionalBarcodes>222</additionalBarcodes>
                    <availability>4</availability>
                    <backorder>false</backorder>
                    <barcode>222</barcode>
                    <bestTaxable>46.90</bestTaxable>
                    <code>22222</code>
                    <color>black</color>
                    <id>22222</id>
                    <lastUpdate>2021-07-13T16:16:57.740Z</lastUpdate>
                    <model>M</model>
                    <modelWeight>0.5</modelWeight>
                    <size>M</size>
                    <streetPrice>93.09</streetPrice>
                    <suggestedPrice>82.00</suggestedPrice>
                    <taxable>46.90</taxable>
                </model>
            </models>
            <name>Calvin Klein Jeans Pantaloni Uomo</name>
            <online>true</online>
            <localizations>
                <description />
                <metaDescription />
                <metaKeywords />
                <metaTitle />
                <name />
                <urlKey />
            </localizations>
            <streetPrice>93.09</streetPrice>
            <suggestedPrice>82.00</suggestedPrice>
            <tags>
                <tag>
                    <hidden>false</hidden>
                    <id>1</id>
                    <name>brand</name>
                    <priority>0</priority>
                    <value>
                        <value>Calvin Klein Jeans</value>
                    </value>
                </tag>
                <tag>
                    <hidden>false</hidden>
                    <id>4</id>
                    <name>category</name>
                    <priority>0</priority>
                    <value>
                        <value>Clothing</value>
                    </value>
                </tag>
                <tag>
                    <hidden>false</hidden>
                    <id>5</id>
                    <name>subcategory</name>
                    <priority>0</priority>
                    <value>
                        <value>Men-Trousers</value>
                    </value>
                </tag>
                <tag>
                    <hidden>false</hidden>
                    <id>11</id>
                    <name>season</name>
                    <priority>0</priority>
                    <value>
                        <value>Fall/Winter</value>
                    </value>
                </tag>
                <tag>
                    <hidden>false</hidden>
                    <id>13</id>
                    <name>color</name>
                    <priority>0</priority>
                    <value>
                        <value>black</value>
                    </value>
                </tag>
                <tag>
                    <hidden>false</hidden>
                    <id>26</id>
                    <name>gender</name>
                    <priority>0</priority>
                    <value>
                        <value>Men</value>
                    </value>
                </tag>
                <tag>
                    <hidden>true</hidden>
                    <id>30</id>
                    <name>productname</name>
                    <priority>0</priority>
                    <value>
                        <value>OFF PLACED</value>
                    </value>
                </tag>
                <tag>
                    <hidden>false</hidden>
                    <id>104</id>
                    <name>brandType</name>
                    <priority>0</priority>
                    <value>
                        <value>luxury</value>
                    </value>
                </tag>
                <tag>
                    <hidden>false</hidden>
                    <id>108</id>
                    <name>subcategoryGriffati</name>
                    <priority>0</priority>
                    <value>
                        <value>Men-Trousers</value>
                    </value>
                </tag>
            </tags>
            <taxable>46.90</taxable>
            <vatClassId>1</vatClassId>
            <weight>0.5</weight>
        </item>
    </items>
</page>
```

My class structure:

```
using System;
using System.Xml.Serialization;
using System.Collections.Generic;
namespace Xml2CSharp
{
    [XmlRoot(ElementName="image")]
    public class Image {
        [XmlElement(ElementName="id")]
        public string Id { get; set; }
        [XmlElement(ElementName="url")]
        public string Url { get; set; }
    }

    [XmlRoot(ElementName="pictures")]
    public class Pictures {
        [XmlElement(ElementName="image")]
        public List<Image> Image { get; set; }
    }

    [XmlRoot(ElementName="model")]
    public class Model {
        [XmlElement(ElementName="additionalBarcodes")]
        public string AdditionalBarcodes { get; set; }
        [XmlElement(ElementName="availability")]
        public string Availability { get; set; }
        [XmlElement(ElementName="backorder")]
        public string Backorder { get; set; }
        [XmlElement(ElementName="barcode")]
        public string Barcode { get; set; }
        [XmlElement(ElementName="bestTaxable")]
        public string BestTaxable { get; set; }
        [XmlElement(ElementName="code")]
        public string Code { get; set; }
        [XmlElement(ElementName="color")]
        public string Color { get; set; }
        [XmlElement(ElementName="id")]
        public string Id { get; set; }
        [XmlElement(ElementName="lastUpdate")]
        public string LastUpdate { get; set; }
        [XmlElement(ElementName="model")]
        public string Model { get; set; }
        [XmlElement(ElementName="modelWeight")]
        public string ModelWeight { get; set; }
        [XmlElement(ElementName="size")]
        public string Size { get; set; }
        [XmlElement(ElementName="streetPrice")]
        public string StreetPrice { get; set; }
        [XmlElement(ElementName="suggestedPrice")]
        public string SuggestedPrice { get; set; }
        [XmlElement(ElementName="taxable")]
        public string Taxable { get; set; }
    }

    [XmlRoot(ElementName="models")]
    public class Models {
        [XmlElement(ElementName="model")]
        public List<Model> Model { get; set; }
    }

    [XmlRoot(ElementName="localizations")]
    public class Localizations {
        [XmlElement(ElementName="description")]
        public string Description { get; set; }
        [XmlElement(ElementName="metaDescription")]
        public string MetaDescription { get; set; }
        [XmlElement(ElementName="metaKeywords")]
        public string MetaKeywords { get; set; }
        [XmlElement(ElementName="metaTitle")]
        public string MetaTitle { get; set; }
        [XmlElement(ElementName="name")]
        public string Name { get; set; }
        [XmlElement(ElementName="urlKey")]
        public string UrlKey { get; set; }
    }

    [XmlRoot(ElementName="value")]
    public class Value {
        [XmlElement(ElementName="value")]
        public string Value { get; set; }
    }

    [XmlRoot(ElementName="tag")]
    public class Tag {
        [XmlElement(ElementName="hidden")]
        public string Hidden { get; set; }
        [XmlElement(ElementName="id")]
        public string Id { get; set; }
        [XmlElement(ElementName="name")]
        public string Name { get; set; }
        [XmlElement(ElementName="priority")]
        public string Priority { get; set; }
        [XmlElement(ElementName="value")]
        public Value Value { get; set; }
    }

    [XmlRoot(ElementName="tags")]
    public class Tags {
        [XmlElement(ElementName="tag")]
        public List<Tag> Tag { get; set; }
    }

    [XmlRoot(ElementName="item")]
    public class Item {
        [XmlElement(ElementName="availability")]
        public string Availability { get; set; }
        [XmlElement(ElementName="bestTaxable")]
        public string BestTaxable { get; set; }
        [XmlElement(ElementName="code")]
        public string Code { get; set; }
        [XmlElement(ElementName="currency")]
        public string Currency { get; set; }
        [XmlElement(ElementName="id")]
        public string Id { get; set; }
        [XmlElement(ElementName="pictures")]
        public Pictures Pictures { get; set; }
        [XmlElement(ElementName="intangible")]
        public string Intangible { get; set; }
        [XmlElement(ElementName="intra")]
        public string Intra { get; set; }
        [XmlElement(ElementName="madein")]
        public string Madein { get; set; }
        [XmlElement(ElementName="models")]
        public Models Models { get; set; }
        [XmlElement(ElementName="name")]
        public string Name { get; set; }
        [XmlElement(ElementName="online")]
        public string Online { get; set; }
        [XmlElement(ElementName="localizations")]
        public Localizations Localizations { get; set; }
        [XmlElement(ElementName="streetPrice")]
        public string StreetPrice { get; set; }
        [XmlElement(ElementName="suggestedPrice")]
        public string SuggestedPrice { get; set; }
        [XmlElement(ElementName="tags")]
        public Tags Tags { get; set; }
        [XmlElement(ElementName="taxable")]
        public string Taxable { get; set; }
        [XmlElement(ElementName="vatClassId")]
        public string VatClassId { get; set; }
        [XmlElement(ElementName="weight")]
        public string Weight { get; set; }
        [XmlAttribute(AttributeName="xsi", Namespace="http://www.w3.org/2000/xmlns/")]
        public string Xsi { get; set; }
        [XmlAttribute(AttributeName="type", Namespace="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance")]
        public string Type { get; set; }
    }

    [XmlRoot(ElementName="items")]
    public class Items {
        [XmlElement(ElementName="item")]
        public List<Item> Item { get; set; }
    }

    [XmlRoot(ElementName="page")]
    public class Page {
        [XmlElement(ElementName="query")]
        public string Query { get; set; }
        [XmlElement(ElementName="items")]
        public Items Items { get; set; }
        [XmlAttribute(AttributeName="totalPages")]
        public string TotalPages { get; set; }
        [XmlAttribute(AttributeName="totalNumberOfElements")]
        public string TotalNumberOfElements { get; set; }
        [XmlAttribute(AttributeName="pageSize")]
        public string PageSize { get; set; }
        [XmlAttribute(AttributeName="lastUpdate")]
        public string LastUpdate { get; set; }
        [XmlAttribute(AttributeName="currentPage")]
        public string CurrentPage { get; set; }
    }

}
```

I made above classes structure using `https://xmltocsharp.azurewebsites.net/`

My deserialization code:

```
using (var stringReader = new StringReader(xml))
{
    var serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Page));
    var xmlReaderSettings = new XmlReaderSettings
    {
        DtdProcessing = DtdProcessing.Parse
    };
    using var xmlReader = XmlReader.Create(stringReader, xmlReaderSettings);
    page = serializer.Deserialize(xmlReader) as Page;
}
```

Deserialization produces the error

> The specified type was not recognized: name='product', namespace='', at .

How do I structure/annotate my POCOs so that the XML above can be deserialized?

Comment: Have you tried to add [XmlType] annotation to Item class with Namespace and TypeName attributes?

Comment: Yes, I have already tried [XmlType(Namespace = "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance", TypeName = "product")]